# Certificate issue to download openjdk12 from java.net

Tags: java, certificate

It seems that the certificate to download the latest openjdk 12 has an issue. The certificate used is for oracle.com.

```
➜  Downloads wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk12.0.1/69cfe15208a647278a19ef0990eea691/12/GPL/openjdk-12.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
--2019-04-29 12:58:12--  https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk12.0.1/69cfe15208a647278a19ef0990eea691/12/GPL/openjdk-12.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving download.java.net (download.java.net)... 23.215.18.120
Connecting to download.java.net (download.java.net)|23.215.18.120|:443... connected.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘download.java.net’
```

[image: download.oracle.com]

Anyone has this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a problem with a vendor's download site, not a programming question.  You should contact the vendor directly.

Answer (score 0):

Certificate gets expired, it is only valid till "Friday,September 20 2019"
Oracle needs to renew certificate.

Comment: But today is 29 April 2019, so 20 September 2019 is in the future. The certificate is not yet expired.

Comment: Its my bad, It is due to URL name is different. Instead of https://download.java.net/, right URL is https://download.oracle.com

Certificate common name is different hence browser is giving this error